# DynamoDB pricing: do I get charged for a full hour if I just create and delete a table for a few minutes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm a little confused by how pricing for DynamoDB works.

Let's say I create a table with 10k write capacity, @ $0.00065 per hour each.  If I delete my table after a minute, do I still pay the $6.50?  If I make new ones after deleting the old ones, am I paying $6.50 every time, even though only there is only ever one at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. When you create anything that is billed by the usage-hour pattern, you will be charged for the entire hour.

As for creating the table afresh post-deletion, you won't be charged an additional $6.5 until the whole hour from the creation of first table is over. This however needs that the old table was deleted completely before creating the new one.

Comment: The pricing page says that it's metered hourly. 
 Does that mean that it's the average amount provisioned throughout that hour? Or the total number of instances of units provisioned?
 https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/

Comment: @lifeformed Lets say at `t=0` you created your table with 10 write capacity. At `t=10`, you create another table with 10 more writes and at `t=15` you delete first table and confirming the deletion, create 3rd table at `t=20` for 5 units. All `t` values are in minutes. After `t=60`, you are billed for 10+10 units, and at `t=120`, you'll be billed for 10+5 units.

Comment: Oh I see, so it's the maximum summed value during that hour?  So if I just flickered one table on and off in one second, and it had 10,000 capacity, and I didn't make any other tables that hour, I still get charged for the full 10,000?  Sounds like I have to be careful when testing this then.

Comment: @lifeformed yes

Comment: @hjpotter92 Do you have any documentation for it being the maximum sum during the hour? I can't find anything

Comment: @Mars It was what I observed in my billings when playing with it across several accounts and services.

Comment: @Mars do note that it is not the same behaviour with EC2. Where you are billed as soon as an instance goes into the 'running' state. So if you flick off and on the same instance, you will be billed for 2 instance-hours.

Comment: @hjpotter92 The docs mentions that it measures hourly (at a different time based on account). Think it's possible it's just a random sample rather than maximum of the hour?

Answer (score 0):

We had a related, but not entirely similar question for AWS, namely: If we set provisioned capacity for a table higher for less than an hour, are we charged for the whole hour or for part of the hour?

Our use case: regular provision capacity of 5 WCU, with a 20 minute increase to 40.000 WCU.

I think their answer is relevant for more people, so just posting it here.

> "Pricing for DynamoDB Provisioned Capacity is calculated per hour, and
> how the provisioned capacity is computed for the hour is by picking a
> random data point within the hour, and charging for that. In other
> words, **when it comes to provisioned capacity being billed, a random
> point within the hour is selected and used as the total provisioned
> capacity measure for that hour.**
>
> As within your use-case you have gone up to 40,000 WCU for 20mins
> roughly, there is another 40 minutes within that hour window where the
> provisioned capacity is 5 WCU. As such, the random minute point that
> is being chosen to be billed for that hour is within this period.
> Hence why the bill for this period is lower than calculated."